# Android Studio - Generate Signed Bundle or APK - Create New Keystore - Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:- Xverify:none

Tags: android

I have written an Android app in Kotlin, using Android Studio. I'm trying to generate a signed Bundle/APK in Android Studio in MacOS, selecting the 'Android App Bundle' option in the first window that appears.

I select 'create new key store' in the following window and fill in the appropriate fields, but when I finish and click ok I get this error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:- Xverify:none
```

I've tried a few solutions, all via the terminal:

```
unset _JAVA_OPTIONS

JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME/tmp"

_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS" && unset _JAVA_OPTIONS &&  alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

But, still I'm getting an error when I try to generate a signed bundle. How do I stop this error so the new key store is created successfully?

Comment: Just try executing `unset _JAVA_OPTIONS` on terminal, without closing the terminal try generating the signed APK

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I get the same error when I try this approach